# How to pass additional arguments to jquery slider 'value' method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using this:

```
$('#theSlider').slider('value', newValue);
```

But how do I pass additional arguments? I tried:

```
$('#theSlider').slider('value', newValue, somethingElse);
```

and

```
$('#theSlider').slider('value', [newValue, somethingElse]);
```

but neither worked. Is it possible to pass additional arguments?

Comment: why do you want to pass additional arguments, the [value](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) method takes only 1 value

Comment: What is something else?

Comment: Is this a value or a different parameter, Or you want to pass two values for `value`

Comment: if you are using a range slider it is possible like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wujwLh0r/1/

Comment: But what for? What is the 'something else'? You can give it `.slider('value', 'blue', 'car', 'circle')`, it just won't care because the slider is not intended to deal with such parameters. So what's your point exactly?

Comment: I can't see why it matters what my reasons for this are, either you can or you can't. I need to know if the slider is being moded by something external, like when clicking on an icon.

Comment: My client wants the slider positioned in the middle ona  10 step scale (1-10), I set it's css to 50%, but if you then click on the slider handle, don't move it and release the mouse button, the change method is called and a span that show sthe current value gets updated with the value 1, even though the handle is still positioned 50% along its length

Comment: somethingElse should be a boolean value that I can then use in my sliders change method

Answer (score 0):

Passing multiple `params` in `.slider()` and `values` having an `array`.

```
$('#theSlider').slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      values: [75, 100]
});
```